# R How to merge multipolygons to polygon

Tags: r, polygon, r-sf

I have a polygon dataset in Simple Feature format that I dissolve based on a ID column like this, using the sf package with R:

```
small_polygons <- small_polygons %>% group_by(dissolve_id) %>% summarise()
```

This works fine, however, it produces some MULTIPOLYGONS. When I cast them back to POLYGONS (`st_cast(small_polygons, "POLYGON")`), the number of polygons rises, because the MULTIPOLYGONS are split in separate polygons.

What I want is to merge each MULTIPOLYGON to a dissolved single POLYGON. How could this be done?

Comment: You can try `st_cast(small_polygons, "POLYGON", do_split = FALSE)`

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Comment: However, this throws this warning: `In st_cast.MULTIPOLYGON(X[[i]], ...) : polygon from first part only`. So this drops parts of the polygons. Any idea how to keep every part of the multipolygon?

Comment: Without seeing your data it is hard to tell, but if the multipolygons can't be merged into a polygon (for example if they are completely separated) then there's no way to dissolve them into a polygon and keep all parts.

Comment: It seems to help to first cast everything to MULTIPOLYGON using `st_cast(small_polygons, "MULTIPOLYGON")` and then cast to POLYGON.

Comment: `st_simplify` is another option